# Joining two subqueries throwing error

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, join

What's wrong with the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Start, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date1, 
   SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Start, End)) / 3600 AS Hours
   FROM timeslot WHERE UserID = 1
   GROUP BY Date1) AS A 

LEFT OUTER JOIN

  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TakenAt, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date2
   FROM snapshot WHERE Deleted = 1
   GROUP BY Date2) AS B 

ON A.Date1 = B.Date2
```

It doesn't run. VS changes the query slightly (changing `GROUP BY Date1` and `GROUP BY Date2` to `GROUP BY A.Date1` and `GROUP BY B.Date2` respectively) and tells me about **unknown column A.Date1 in the group statement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening because of [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) , try using back ticks ` :

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Start`, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date1, 
   SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `Start`, `End`)) / 3600 AS Hours
   FROM timeslot WHERE UserID = 1
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Start`, '%d-%M-%Y')) A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TakenAt, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date2
   FROM snapshot WHERE Deleted = 1
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TakenAt, '%d-%M-%Y')) B 
ON A.Date1 = B.Date2
```

Or just alias every thing:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.Start, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date1, 
   SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t.Start, t.End)) / 3600 AS Hours
   FROM timeslot t WHERE t.UserID = 1
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.Start, '%d-%M-%Y') ) A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.TakenAt, '%d-%M-%Y') AS Date2
   FROM snapshot s WHERE s.Deleted = 1
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(s.TakenAt, '%d-%M-%Y')) B 
ON A.Date1 = B.Date2
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with both these queries.

Comment: `unknown column t.Date1 in the group statement` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try it now, and you didn't say what's the error with the original query. @dotNET

Comment: hmm... works now. btw, I did mention the error message (in **bold**). Any thoughts on why it doesn't work with column aliases?

Comment: Yes, because the alias belong to the table , so only the tables columns can be reffered with that alias, and when you used `A` and `B` then the alias is in the outer query, and can't be called from an inner query, it works only the other way around @dotNET . And again, in **bold** you said what's the error where you change the query, you didn't say it's the same without the change:)

Comment: But I didn't specify `A` or `B` in the inner queries. It is Visual Studio that modifies the queries and inserts `A.` and `B.` in the `Group By` clauses when I run the query.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about MySQL, but in most DBMS you can use the columns caculated in the select, in the `GROUP BY` clause. @dotNET